# Launching default apps with intents

Tags: android, android-intent, default, package, message

How, in android, do I start an app set as the default (i.e. Handcent for Messaging, Dolphin for browsing)?

I can only find how to use definite package names for intents:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        switch (position) {
        case 0: //messages
            i.setPackage("com.android.mms");
            break;
        case 1: //inbox
            i.setPackage("com.android.email");
            break;
        case 2: //browser
            i.setPackage("com.android.browser");
        default:
            i = null;
        }
```

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to set an app as a default for an intent?

Comment: Yes, can you clarify your question, I'm not sure if you're trying to set a default app or just launch an Activity with an intent...

Comment: Sorry about not being clear. Basically I'm making a home app where clicking the "Messages" bit in a listview will show the default messages app, the "Browser" launching the default browser etc. but I didn't know how to do this.

The code above was just a bit of a fudge (by launching the normal android apps) until someone answered this :)

I guess I have to use intents and categories etc but I find them really confusing. For example, there is an ACTION_SEND (which I assume you can use to send an sms) but I only want to open the default sms program, not send one. Hope that's clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How, in android, do I start an app set as the default (i.e. Handcent for Messaging, Dolphin for browsing)?

"Default" is for a specific operation (e.g., sending a message), not for some abstract notion of "Messaging" in general.

Also, the code you are showing above uses things that are not in the SDK (namely, specific packages). Your code will break on some devices, where the device manufacturer has replaced the app. Your code may break in future versions of Android, when the stock apps are refactored or otherwise renamed.

I think you need to reconsider what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok, cool. I thought that I'd have to do it using intents and categories and stuff but I don't really understand them yet so I thought I'd try another way.

So, to start the messaging app, should I pass an Intent with ACTION_SEND or something? I'd be grateful if you could explain it to me.

Comment: Ok, so there isn't a way to open the default messaging app full stop? Damn. Oh well, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can search for apps that satisfy a given Intent (e.g., ACTION_SEND), decide which one you want, retrieve its component name, and then launch it with a different Intent that specifies the component name.

Start with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(...);
List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
    intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```